# Binding public property in UserControl to property on parent does not work

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Binding to a usercontrols dependencyproperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216714/binding-to-a-usercontrols-dependencyproperties)

I'm attempting to create a WPF UserControl that contains a grid of data. I want the UserControl to get its data by explicitly binding an exposed public property to a list of Projects on the view hosting the user control like shown below.

If I set a breakpoint in the setter of the ProjectList property, it never goes in there.

I'm trying to bind the ProjectList property to both the Projects in the hosting view and to the grid in the UserControl itself which I'm not sure is right, but I don't think it should cause this problem.

My instantiation of the UserControl:

```
<uc:ProjectCardViewGrid x:Name="ProjectListUC" ProjectList="{Binding Projects, Mode=OneWay}"   Title="{Binding CreateNewPlan}" Grid.Row="1" />
```

My UserControl is defined like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ProjectCardViewGrid"             
       ...
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
         xmlns:dxlc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/layoutcontrol" 
         xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"                    
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
         Loaded="UserControl_Loaded_1">
<Grid x:Name="UserLayoutMaster">       
    <dxg:GridControl Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ProjectListGrid" Height="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}" ShowBorder="False">
```

My ProjectList DependencyProperty looks like this...

```
Public Property ProjectList As List(Of Project)
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(ProjectListProperty), List(Of Project))
    End Get
    Set(value As List(Of Project))

        SetValue(ProjectListProperty, value)

        NotifyPropertyChanged()

    End Set
End Property

Public Shared ReadOnly ProjectListProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ProjectList", GetType(List(Of Project)), GetType(ProjectCardViewGrid), New PropertyMetadata(Nothing))
```

EDIT: This is the updated code but setting a breakpoint in the Callback event handler, it still doesn't get hit.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly TitleProperty As DependencyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Title",
        GetType(String),
        GetType(ProjectCardViewGrid),
        New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            Nothing,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender,
            New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf TitleChanged)))

Public Property Title As String
    Get
        Return CType(GetValue(TitleProperty), String)
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        SetValue(TitleProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub TitleChanged(ByVal d As DependencyObject, ByVal e As DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)

End Sub
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2243174/1136211) or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9147250/1136211) for a solution, and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217212/1136211) for an explanation why the setter isn't called.

Comment: That's not the way DependencyProperties work, also, what does your `NotifyPropertyChanged()` do?

Comment: Clemens, I implemented the Callback as shown and it is never raised either. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. And did you also fix the binding by either setting the `DataContext` or specifying `ElementName`? The PropertyChangedCallback would only be necessary if you need to do more than binding to the property. Consider posting the changed code. Please include @Clemens in your comment, otherwise i won't get notified.

Comment: @Clemens. I posted an edit. Not understanding it much, I implemented it exactly as Microsoft's article shows. It doesn't hit a break point in the event handler either.

Comment: @Clemens Forgot to address the part about the DataContext. The data context has always been set at the UserControl level as DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}".

Comment: @Clemens I just showed the Title property. The ProjectList property is still there. Both properties exhibit the same behavior (or lack thereof). Sorry, but I'm clearly in a bit over my head. Thanks.

Comment: @DannyEllisJr. And setting `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` does not work for me. Try setting `DataContext = this;` in the UserControl's constructor. And when you say "It doesn't hit a break point in the event handler either", you mean in the TitleChanged callback, where there is no code?

Comment: @Clemens I have other properties on the form that are binding correctly, so I know the DataContext is getting set correctly. I tried it anyway to be sure. The issue is just these two properties I'm attempting to pass in from the UserControl's parent.

Comment: @Clemens I removed DataContext=... and did not assign a data source and sudden the events started firing. However, without a data source I'm unsure how to bind the controls ON the user control.

Comment: When you say "the events started firing" you mean that the PropertyChangedCallback is called? Proves that you bindings work. Unless you explicitly set the DataContext in the UserControl's constructor, it will be inherited from the container or window that contains the UserControl.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your help. I had to implement the callback as you originally suggested and not specify binding at the user control level. Each of my properties I had to bind like so...

    ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"

But it finally works. Thanks again!